# iOS appcache suddenly ignored

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I have been given the task of building a web-app for a magazine that will be displayed to people using an iPad. Users are encouraged to save it to their home-screen and it has been designed to be usable when offline.

I thought it was working fine, however a client has noticed an issue: after a few minutes, and closing and re-opening the app a bit, the cache resets and it won't load various assets. Some HTML and CSS comes through but when I inspect via the Safari debugging tools, it is complaining that it can't access various images, some javascript and - interestingly - the appcache file itself.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing iOS/Safari to suddenly ignore my appcache, or at least parts of it?

Comment: Is the device running low on storage and removed cached files? How much space do you have free?

Comment: Nope - I'm testing with the iPad simulator which I reset before I begin testing so it's completely clear. I then visit the app and let it cache all the JS, download the magazine stories, etc.